# How To Do Validation in Silverlight/RIA When A Call To Database Is Required?

Tags: c#, silverlight, validation, ria

I feel like there is a better way to do this than how I am doing it now.

I am using Silverlight 4, RIA and EF (with an Oracle adapter). I am inserting a record into a table and doing a lot of validation on it with Validation attributes, but I have one piece of validation that requires querying the DB to check existing records before the new one can be inserted (this seems like it should be common and easy requirement, no?)

Right now, I am doing this client-side with an Invoke method on the DomainService. This seems lame and dumb. But I can't figure out how to do this server-side where it really belongs.

It seems like there should be a way to handle all of this server-side and inform the client of a validation error, but I can't quite figure it out and hardly anyone seems to approach this one particular validation scenario.

Comment: Hi, you should have a bridge between SL UI and business logic, either WCF via async, firing an event and handling its completed method or with RIA Services, which nicely wraps this all for you. The whole db interaction logic and query/update should be in the business layer than you can imagine the UI gets a true or false in the completed method if everything went fine or failed.

Comment: Do you have an example Davide? Because that's a pretty vague answer. I work better seeing actual code, ya know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF RIA provides a means to attach validation to entities on the serverside. You build a class as detailed below naming it Rules.

```
public static partial class FooRules
{
  public static ValidationResult FooIDUnique(Foo foo, ValidationContext context)
  {
    bool check = false;

    using (FooEntities fe = new FooEntities())
    { 
      check = fe.Foo.Any(f => f.FooId == foo.fooId); 
    }
    if (!check)
      return ValidationResult.Success;

    return new ValidationResult("FooID error msg,", new string[] { "FooID" });
  }
}
```

I've put together an example app that shows adding validation client and server side with RIA.

You can download it [here](http://bit.ly/dUkKBD).

Comment: That won't compile Rus. As soon as I try and use FooEntities (name changed correctly of course) it bombs on the compile. Tells me I'm missing a namespace, but it doesn't make any sense...

Comment: All your rules classes client or server side should be in the .Web (server side) namespace irrespective of whether they are physically in the client or server side projects. Other than that paste the compile error in here and I'll try and help.

Comment: The type or namespace name 'FooEntities' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). As soon as I try and new up FooEntities in that partial class, it bombs. I can do any kind of property/entity validation I want to with those sorts of static validation methods (stored on the server side) but as soon as I try and get the Entities context involved, no dice.

Comment: Chris, I've put together an little app to help explain things. Hope its useful. The URL for it is in the answer above.

Comment: Really weird. I couldn't get it to work no matter what. Then my computer bombed, I rebooted, and this worked... Microsoft Voodoo Magic at work again I guess. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to link to the specific entry but check out this thread....

http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/212555/502113.aspx